# Bootstrap 4 grid issue safari

Tags: safari, bootstrap-4

I am trying to find best workaround for grid issue on older versions of safari, because any of them which I found not working for me.

The problem is that bootstrap grid is not working correctly. In my project I have simple code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      1 col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      2 col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      3 col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      4 col
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

4th column should moved to another line but it's on same line and it breaks also body width.

I tried different solutions but it's not working for me. Only when I overwrite grid in this way:

```
.col-lg-4 {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Two columns are on second line but it's also wrong because only one column should be there.

I tried also with:

```
.row:before, .row:after {display: none !important;}
```

and

```
 .row { width: 100%; }                                                 
 .col { display:inline-block !important; }
```

but without success. I am testing on this user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_14 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4
```

What's the best workaround for that?